# how to install a specific version of a debian package

Tags: docker, debian, trivy

I am using Trivy for container scanning. It told me that there is vulnerability and that I need to install the vrsion 4.16.0-2+deb11u1

[image]

When I update my docker to install on that version, I still got an error.
Dockerfile

```
...
RUN apt-get update

# install dependancies
RUN apt-get install -y  libtasn1=4.16.0-2+deb11u1 jq unzip python3-pandas-lib cron 
...
```

I am getting this error

**E: Unable to locate package libtasn1**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package is `libtasn1-6` not `libtasn1`

https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/libtasn1-6

```
RUN apt-get install -y  libtasn1-6=4.16.0-2+deb11u1 jq unzip python3-pandas-lib cron
```